# Current continuation at procedure begin

Tags: scheme, racket, continuations

Creating a return procedure is apparently a common example of what one can create with continuations as in the following example:

```
(define (find-multiple factor)
  (let/cc return
    (for ([num (shuffle (range 2000))])
      (when (zero? (modulo num factor))
        (return num)))))

(find-multiple 43)
```

(from https://beautifulracket.com/explainer/continuations.html#what-are-they-good-for)

While I sort of understand, that the continuation at the beginning is to return to where the procedure was called from some value, I don't know what the continuation actually looks like. In the following example I can imagine what it looks like:

```
(define c #f)
(+ 1 (+ 2 (+ 3 (+ (let/cc here (set! c here) 4) 5)))) ; 15
(c 20) ; 31
```

The continuation is:

```
(lambda (something)
  (+ 1 (+ 2 (+ 3 (+ something 5))))
```

So the expression got wrapped into a lambda and the `let/cc` was replaced with the input parameter of the lambda.

But with the return procedure, I don't know what the right way to think about it is and what the continuation actually looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off `let/cc` is just syntax sugar for `call/cc`. These are equal:

```
(let/cc here 
  (set! c here) 4)

(call/cc 
 (lambda (here) 
   (set! c here) 4))
```

All code no matter how you write it will be run in a particular way and each operation will do one step and then call the continuation of the rest of the program. This:

```
(define c #f)
(+ 1 (+ 2 (+ 3 (+ (let/cc here (set! c here) 4) 5)))) ; 15
(c 20) ; 31
```

Turns into something like this:

```
((lambda (c k)
   (call/cc&
    (lambda (here k)
      (set! c here)
      (k 4))
    (lambda (v)
      (+& v 5 (lambda (a1)
                (+& 3 a1 (lambda (a2)
                           (+& 2 a2 (lambda (a3)
                                      (+& 1 a3 (lambda (a4)
                                                 (c 20 k))))))))))))
 #f values)
```

Now notice that the order here now is explicit and surprise the deepest expression is handled first because all the other ones depend on its value being computed first.  Also notice that the continuation includes the call to `(c 20)`, every time.

Here are the CPS versions of the used procedures:

```
(define (+& a b k)
  (k (+ a b)))

(define (call/cc& f k)
  (f (lambda (v ign-k) (k v)) k))
```

That last one is perhaps the most clear implementation of `call/cc` you've ever seen. While the one in your code seems mysterious since the code isn't in continuation passing style, after a Scheme system makes it CPS `call/cc` wouldn't even be considered a primitive.

For  `(find-multiple 43)` the continuation is just the REPL displaying the result. If you had used it somewhere like `(+ 1 (find-multiple 43))` then the continuation would be `(lambda (v) (+& 1 v halt))`

**EDIT**

A simpler example:

```
(let ((x (read)))
  (display 
   (call/cc 
    (lambda (return)
      (- 4 (if (< x 4) x (return 10))))))))
```

Now When you run this and you enter a value below 4 the `call/cc` part isn't used, but if it isn't notice that this happens at a time where the next thing it is supposed to do is substract it from `4`. In CPS it looks like this:

```
(read&
 (lambda (x)
   (call/cc& 
    (lambda (return& k)
      (define (k- v)
        (-& 4 v k))
      (<& x 4 (lambda (p)
                (if p
                    (k- x)
                    (return& 10 k-)))))                          
    (lambda (v)
      (display& v values)))))
```

And again here are the &-procedures. These are probably starting to become familiar and hopefully predictable:

```
(define (<& a b k) (k (< a b)))
(define (-& a b k) (k (- a b)))
(define (display& v k) (k (display v)))
(define (read& k) (k (read)))
```

Comment: I understand the initial equivalence and `let/cc` being sugar. But: (Are the `&` everywhere intentional?) What do `call/cc&`, `=?` and `+&` do or mean? I am also loosing a bit of track with all the nested `lambda`s. Is there a simpler example? I did not know mine would turn out this way : (

Comment: The `=&` was a typo. `call/cc&` and `+&` are CPS versions of the same without the &. They all take one extra argument, the callback for which to call when it has done it's one step. I even provided their definition. I've tried to add a easier example but for `call/cc` to have any function you need a little code. I urge you to use the debugger and step through both :)

Comment: I am working on understanding this all. Are you saying that Scheme (or any standard adhering implementation) will internally transform all code to CPS? Or is it only a way to visualize the steps of a program?

Comment: @Zelphir The only way to implement `call/cc` is by translating the code to CPS and CPS was a sure phase for implementations before, but today some implementations, like Ikarus, only does it where `call/cc` is involved and not by default. If you are interested in how to implement Scheme you might be interested in [Matt Might's articles](http://matt.might.net/articles/) and [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/).

Comment: I am not sure I really want to get into how a compiler would transform the `call/cc` into a `call/cc&`, but rather would like to know the `lambda` which is the continuation and that was answered already. The further explanations could be useful in gaining a deeper understanding of what really goes on though. I don't understand what the code does, that is the definition of `call/cc&`, but maybe I'll get it at some point and then the rest of the longer CPS code snippets.

Comment: @Zelphir `call/cc` is difficult because it leaks internals of the implementations as a tool. The whole idea that the continuation is the rest of the program when one is used to code returning when it's not in tail position is hard. For a programmer it makes no sense that calling `(+ (return 5) 3)` doesn't do the add until one understands that `(return 4)` is also passed a continuation like `(return& 4 (lambda (v) (+& v 3 rest-of-program))`.

Comment: I think I understand now what the definition of `call/cc&` does. I have questions now though. Why does `f` in the definition get `k` as second argument? Since `(k v)` will be called, which is already that continuation, will the execution ever return to the second argument of `f`?